# Hitting Objects Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to find a proper algorithm for this problem

Given the blow points

[image]

The target is find the least number of lines to be drawn

Example result

[image]

I googled and some algorithms poped up such as Greedy algorithm, approximation algorithm but I'm sure how they're fit to this problem.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Heuristically speaking, it seems like you could try a number of slopes, and sort by slopes that match the most number of points. This is likely to be terrible algorithmically. Also, can lines cross?

Comment: Looks like a [Set-Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) problem to me. Create all the sets of co-linear points first, then find the minimal set of sets that covers all points.

Comment: @IanMercer Agree. I guess "terrible algorithmically" is a euphemism for NP problems!

Comment: Thanks @IanMercer, I picked up your key word "co-linear" and I found out "slope" to  determine if points are collinear in coordinate and I think I got it's working now